# Templating – Pass variable references in Python from a config file

Tags: python, configuration-files, template-engine

A ticketing script is accepting input from a config file. That config file contains an email body. How do I best enable the customer to reference a static list of variables within that email body?

The way I am doing it now is training the user which variables are allowed, and having the variables be "escaped" by mustaches, like so:

Config file:

```
You have been assigned a ticket to fix {IP}. The host contains the following vulnerabilities:
{vulnerability}

The urgency is {priority}.
```

The script will take this email body and send out an email for each server it finds. For example, there are 2 servers, A and B. The script will send out the following emails:

Server A values:

- IP = 192.168.1.2
- vulnerability = 'Heartbleed on port 443'
- priority = 'High'

Server A email output:

```
You have been assigned a ticket to fix 192.168.1.2. The host contains the following vulnerabilities:
Heartbleed on port 443

The urgency is High.
```

Server B values:

- IP = 192.168.1.11
- vulnerability = 'OpenOffice 1.3'
- priority = 'Low'

Server B email output:

```
You have been assigned a ticket to fix 192.168.1.11. The host contains the following vulnerabilities:
OpenOffice 1.3

The urgency is Low.
```

The question I am asking, generally speaking, how can I enable a non-Python user be able to customize a string with references to variables?

Comment: not clear for me ...

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to do with more detail

Comment: Including the expected output from that input would help. Also please include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Also, include the config file . If it is too big paste the contents on a site like pastebin.com

Comment: So use a mustache templating engine. There are plenty of them out there. This question makes no sense as written.

Comment: Updated question. Googling mustache templating engine...

Answer (score 0):

Use a mustache templating library like [pystache](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache).

```
>>> import pystache
>>> renderer = pystache.Renderer()
>>> print renderer.render(parsed, {'who': 'Pops'})
Hey Pops!
>>> print renderer.render(parsed, {'who': 'you'})
Hey you!
```